# IIS 7 - Restrict Application by IP Address behind load balancer

Tags: .net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, ip-address

I am trying to restrict an application in IIS 7 by IP address on my web server behind a load balancer. The X-Forwarded-For header is set by the load balancer with the client's IP address.

What is the best way to extract that IP address in IIS 7 to setup IP address filtering on my application? If there is not a best way, I will end up using an HTTPModule to handle this for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to accomplish this.

Add a new inbound rule with conditions that check to see if the IP address does not match {HTTP_X_Forwarded_For}. You can then set the rule up to redirect, rewrite, or abort the request.

You can a new condition for each IP address you wish to white-list.

Answer (score 9):

### Using [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to normalize `REMOTE_ADDR` and implement IP Restrictions.

With the following recipe `REMOTE_ADDR` will be set to the **real** Client-IP regardless if there is a trusted reverse proxy in front to set `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`.  That means you can remove the reverse proxy from in front of IIS and these IP Restrictions will still continue to work as expected.

#### Normalize `REMOTE_ADDR` in `applicationHost.config`

Set this in the global IIS `applicationHost.config`:

```
<rewrite>
    <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="REMOTE_ADDR" />
        <add name="REMOTE_HOST" />
    </allowedServerVariables>
    <globalRules>
        <rule name="Remote" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
            <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^10\.1\.1\.[123]$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}" pattern="\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$" ignoreCase="false" />
            </conditions>
            <serverVariables>
                <set name="REMOTE_ADDR" value="{C:0}" />
                <set name="REMOTE_HOST" value="{C:0}" />
            </serverVariables>
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
    </globalRules>
</rewrite>
```

The recipe above copies the last IP address it finds in `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` to the `REMOTE_ADDR` and `REMOTE_HOST` `<serverVariables>` only if the original value in `REMOTE_ADDR` matches the IP address of a trusted reverse proxy.

To have this recipe work, the first condition must be set to match your reverse proxy's IP address(es):

```
<add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^10\.1\.1\.[123]$" ignoreCase="false" />
```

In the example above, the client IP in `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is trusted only if set by a reverse proxy at one of these IP addresses:

```
10.1.1.1 or 10.1.1.2 or 10.1.1.3
```

That takes care of setting `REMOTE_ADDR` to the **real** Client-IP.

#### IP Restrictions in `web.config`

IP Restrictions can be set with the [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) in a site's `web.config` using this recipe:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="IP Restricted" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^(127\.|10\.20\.74\.|10\.25\.182\.|10\.64\.105\.10)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/403.html" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Edit the `pattern=` to only match the IP addresses or blocks you need to let in.

Change the `<action />` to whatever needed.

Because the `web.config` recipe above filters on the standard `REMOTE_ADDR` variable, it works with and without `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`.  The recipe in `applicationHost.config` `<rewrite>` `<globalRules>` ensures that `REMOTE_ADDR` is always set to the **real** Client-IP for anything that might later reference `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Answer (score 1):

IIS 7 and beyond include the [Dynamic IP Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions) module, which supports filtering client requests by their `X-Forwarded-For` header, which is added to a request [when using an AWS load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-for):

> Support for web servers behind a proxy - If your web server is behind a proxy, you can configure the module to use the client IP address from an X-Forwarded-For header.

[You can enable Proxy Mode support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions#support-for-web-servers-behind-proxy) by checking the "Proxy" checkbox in the module's configuration page, then write rules to allow/deny IPs/CIDR ranges via the module.

Comment: In IIS 8.0+, this module [is called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions) "IP Address and Domain Restrictions," but I did not know about Proxy Mode. Thanks!